# Loading .rmd datafile within a function to the environment

Tags: r, function, readr

I'm new to functions and I would like to load my data with a function. 
The function appears to be correct but the file does not save as a dataframe to the environment, while this does happen when it's not within the function.

This is my script:

```
read_testdata <- function(file) {
  Dataset_test <- read_rds(here("foldername", file))
}

read_testdata("filename")
```

Can someone spot my error?

Comment: Should it be `read_testdata("whateverthefileiscalled.rds")` or `filename="whateverthefileiscalled.rds"` and `read_testdate(filename)`

Comment: The first one so: `read_testdata("whateverthefileiscalled.rds")`

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I spotted my problem, the correct code should be this:

```
read_testdata <- function(file) {
 read_rds(here("foldername", file))


}

Dataset_test <- read_testdata("filename.rds")
```